# Copy to Clipboard in Visualforce

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I need Copy to Clipboard functionality in Visualforce Page, I tried several links but nothing seems to be working.

```
<apex:page title="Clipboard Test" >
<apex:messages />
    <script language="JavaScript">
        function ClipBoard(copytextid, holdtextid) 
        {
            holdtxt = document.getElementById(holdtextid);
            holdtxt.innerText = document.getElementById(copytextid).innerText;
            Copied = holdtxt.createTextRange();
            alert("text in buffer \"" + holdtxt.innerText + "\"");
            Copied.execCommand("Copy");
        }
    </script>   

    <apex:pageblock >
    <apex:form >
        <apex:outputpanel ID="copytext" STYLE="height:150;width:162;background-color:pink">
            Text to Copy
        </apex:outputpanel> 

                <apex:inputtextarea ID="holdtext" STYLE="display:none;">
        </apex:inputtextarea>

        <apex:commandbutton onClick="ClipBoard('{!$Component.copytext}', '{!$Component.holdtext}')" value="Copy to Clipboard"/> 
    </apex:form>
    </apex:pageblock>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: Please post the VFP code which you've tried.

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Not getting any error, but the code is not working

Comment: I have used https://clipboardjs.com/ without issues before.

Comment: Seems like you have not included link to its JS library, See the setup link in the mentioned site. Also you should add rerender to command button otherwise whole page would reload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of errors in your page. The `createTextRange` is specific to InternetExplorer and there is no re-render or `return false;` present in your `<apex:commandbutton` code. Or else the whole page would refresh and the clipboard data will be lost. There are many similar examples you can find in Stackoverflow/JSFiddle. I found one [here](https://jsfiddle.net/alvaroAV/a2pt16yq/). I tried using this JS function in your code as below. Hope this will help.

VF Page code

```
<apex:page title="Clipboard Test" >
<apex:messages />
    <script language="JavaScript">
        function ClipBoard(copytextid, holdtextid){
            copyToClipboard(copytextid);
        }
        function copyToClipboard(elementId) {
          // Create an auxiliary hidden input
          var aux = document.createElement("input");
          // Get the text from the element passed into the input
          aux.setAttribute("value", document.getElementById(elementId).innerHTML);
          // Append the aux input to the body
          document.body.appendChild(aux);
          // Highlight the content
          aux.select();
          // Execute the copy command
          document.execCommand("copy");
          // Remove the input from the body
          document.body.removeChild(aux);
        }    
    </script>   
    <apex:pageblock >
    <apex:form >
        <apex:outputpanel ID="copytext" STYLE="height:150;width:162;background-color:pink">
            Text to Copy
        </apex:outputpanel> 
        <apex:inputtextarea ID="holdtext" STYLE="display:none;"></apex:inputtextarea>
        <apex:commandbutton onClick="ClipBoard('{!$Component.copytext}', '{!$Component.holdtext}');" rerender="copytext" value="Copy to Clipboard"/> 
    </apex:form>
    </apex:pageblock>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 problems with your code:

1. Include `clipboard.js` to the page.
2. Add rerender to `apex:commandButton` otherwise whole page would refresh.

If you want to copy the value from one element to another, that can be done with JavaScript and doesn't specifically need the `clipboard.js` library.

Answer (score 0):

i had similar requirement,i am not getting the result,Can u please help me out.This is my code

```
<apex:page controller="one"> 

<apex:messages />
<script language="JavaScript">
        function ClipBoard(copytextid){
            copyToClipboard(copytextid);
        }
        function copyToClipboard(elementId) {
          // Create an auxiliary hidden input
          var aux = document.createElement("input");
          // Get the text from the element passed into the input
          aux.setAttribute("value", document.getElementById(elementId).innerHTML);
          // Append the aux input to the body
          document.body.appendChild(aux);
          // Highlight the content
          aux.select();
          // Execute the copy command
          document.execCommand("copy");
          // Remove the input from the body
          document.body.removeChild(aux);
        }    
    </script>   

    <apex:form > 
        <apex:pageBlock id="one"> 
           <apex:pageBlockSection >
                    <apex:commandButton value="Generate" reRender="one">                     
                    <apex:param name="RURL" value="{!$Page.Pagee}" assignTo="{!accid}"/> 
                    </apex:commandButton>
               </apex:pageBlockSection>
                <apex:pageBlockSection >                
                Your Referral Link<apex:inputText id="copyText" value="{!accid}"/>                
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:commandbutton onClick="ClipBoard('{!$Component.copytext}');" rerender="one" value="Copy to Clipboard"/> 
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            </apex:pageBlockSection> 
            </apex:pageBlock> 
    </apex:form> 
</apex:page>
```